# jquery ajax change current html only when image is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, loading

I am trying to load a .php file that comes with a 2Mb image in a specific div.

I can achieve this with ajax but my problem is that I only want the current div html changed to the new one when the image is done loading. My problem right now is that my div becomes empty during the loading process.

```
function ajaxcallmap(my_url, my_div, my_data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: my_url,
        data: my_data,
        type: 'get',
        success: function (output) {
            var $imgs = $("#worldmap_container").html(output).find("img"), //hide them
            imgAmount = $imgs.length, 
            imgCounter = 0;

            $imgs.on("load", function () {
                imgCounter++;
                if (imgCounter === imgAmount) {
                    $(my_div).html(output);//show the images when they're loaded
                    ajaxReady();//Recal jQuery Events
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you clear your div somewhere else but not in the above code sample

Comment: i am trying to eliminate the flashing that happens when i change from an image to the other. Happens because it takes a little to load the image. When the images are cached i can barely see the flasing. I dont think i am clearing the div contents at all from another code source.

Comment: Have you tried using the `.ready()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `complete:` function instead of a `success:` function.